# Separation of variables for the heat equation in polar coordinates

Tags: partial-differential-equations, polar-coordinates, heat-equation

> The heat conduction equation in two space dimensions
> may be expressed in terms of polar coordinates as
> $$k(u_{rr} +\dfrac{1}{r} u_r +\dfrac{1}{r^2} u_{θθ}) = u_t.$$
> Assuming that $u(r, θ, t) = R(r)
> \Theta(θ)T (t)$, find ordinary
> differential equations satisfied by $R(r), 
> \Theta(θ)$, and $T (t)$.

This is question question 49 on page 215 of Vector Calculus by Marsden and Tromba. The given answers are:

> $T' + kc_1T = 0, , \Theta'' +c_2\Theta = 0, r^2R' +r R' −c_3R = 0$
> for some constants $c_1, c_2$, and $c_3$.

I have managed to get the first two, but not the last equation. I started by writing $$k(R'' \Theta T + \dfrac{1}{r} R' \Theta T + \dfrac{1}{r^2} R \Theta'' T) = R \Theta T'.$$

I then tried to separate variables, to get one side depending on $t$ only and another depending on $(r,\theta)$. This would mean that both sides would be equal to a common constant, according to [examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4233899/method-of-separation-of-variables-for-heat-equation) [I have seen](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2309586/solving-the-heat-equation-using-the-separation-of-variables). This means that I get $$ \dfrac{R'' \Theta + \dfrac{1}{r} R' \Theta + \dfrac{1}{r^2} R \Theta''}{R\Theta} = \dfrac{R''}{R} + \dfrac{1}{r} \dfrac{R'}{R} + \dfrac{1}{r^2} \dfrac{\Theta''}{\Theta} = \dfrac{T'}{kT} = c_1.$$

This gave me the first equation, which is $T' = kc_1 T$. I then get the other equation as $\dfrac{R''}{R} + \dfrac{1}{r} \dfrac{R'}{R} + \dfrac{1}{r^2} \dfrac{\Theta''}{\Theta} = c_1$ or $$r^2 c_1 - r^2 \dfrac{R''}{R} - r\dfrac{R'}{R} = \dfrac{\Theta''}{\Theta} = c_2,$$ so I obtain $\Theta'' = c_2 \Theta$ and $r^2c_1 - r^2 \dfrac{R''}{R} - r\dfrac{R'}{R} = c_2$ which gave me $$r^2 R'' + rR' + c_2R - r^2 Rc_1 = 0. $$ This is somewhat similar to the printed answer, but I got an extra term with $r^2$. Please, could someone let me know where I went wrong? Thank you very much.

Comment: Your result is correct. Compare with Question 2 in this worksheet: http://math.uchicago.edu/~ecartee/2930/worksheet12.pdf